# question about proving subset inclusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory

normally when one proves subset inclusion, one usually take any $x$ from the subset, and proves that it is also in the superset.

e.g.

Set $A=$ all triangles

Set $B=$ all shapes with a sum of of interior angles of 180 degrees

If I take any $x$ from $A,$ and proves that it is in $B,$ I have proven $A$ is a subset of $B.$

What I don't understand is how can you arbitrarily pick any member of a subset to prove set inclusion. Wouldn't there be a case where you could have picked an element which just happens to be in the superset, while there are elements which are not?

e.g.

Set $C=$ shapes with at least one interior angle of 90 degrees

In this case, if I take any element from $A,$ I may happen to pick a right angled triangle, which would be in $C.$ But surely I haven't proven that $A$ is a subset of $C,$ as not all triangles are right angle!

I know this is a stupid question, but it has been bugging me for a long time, could anyone please help? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you "pick any item" from set $A$, you are only allowed to assume things about $x$ that are true for *all* elements of $A$.

For example, in your case, you say:

> Let $x\in A$ be an element of $A$. Then, we know that $x$ is a triangle, because *all* elements of $A$ are triangles. Now, because $x$ is a triangle, the sum of its interior angles is $180$ degrees, so $x\in B$.

On the other hand, if you pick an element $x\in A$, you **CANNOT** assume that it is a right angled triangle, because not all elements in $A$ are right angled triangles.

Answer (score 1):

When you pick an arbitrary, unspecified element $a$ of $A$ and show that it belongs to $B$ **merely by virtue of being in** $A$, you’re showing that it doesn’t matter which element of $A$ you picked: the mere fact that it’s in $A$ is enough to allow you to conclude that it’s also in $B$. Thus, you’re really talking simultaneously about all elements of $A$: your argument applies equally to all of them, because it uses only facts about $a$ that follow from its membership in $A$. In particular, you don’t attribute to $a$ any special properties that it doesn’t share with every other element of $A$.

To put it a little differently, you’re not really picking a single, specific element of $A$: you’re picking a generic element, one about which you can assume only those things that follow directly from its membership in $A$.

Comment: Thank you so much! So to clarify that I get it, when you pick an arbitrary element from A, the only property we know it has is deduced from the fact that it is a member of A, thus making that property necessarily shared by all members of A. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @Daniel: You are indeed. I should probably mention one slight complication. It might be that members of $A$ are of several different types. In that case your argument will have several different cases, one for each type. In effect you’re writing $A=A_1\cup\ldots\cup A_n$ and showing that each $A_k\subseteq B$.

Comment: @DanielMak That is correct. That's because when you are proving $X\subseteq Y$, you are proving the statement: "For all $x\in X$, the statement $y\in Y$ is true", i.e. you are proving a statement for *all* elements of $X$, so you can only assume properties that are shared by all members of $X$.

Comment: Thank you so much Prof Scott and 5xum! This really solved a big and yet basic problem for me, now I can finally move forward with my study.

Comment: @Daniel: You’re welcome!