# Trying to understand basic Gröbner basis theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, nonlinear-system, groebner-basis

The following is from some study material I was provided. I will interject at the parts that have stumped me.

## Theorem

Let < be a monomial order on the polynomial ring *K[X]*.
Let ⟨0⟩ ≠ *I* ⊂ *K[X]* be an ideal.
Let {*g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, ..., g<sub>s</sub>*} be the Gröbner basis of *I* with respect to <.

Then:

> *I* = ⟨*g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, ..., g<sub>s</sub>*⟩.

### Proof

By assumption, {*g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, ..., g<sub>s</sub>*} is the Gröbner basis of *I* with respect to <.

Hence one has:

> ⟨in<sub><</sub>(*g<sub>1</sub>*), in<sub><</sub>(*g<sub>2</sub>*), ..., in<sub><</sub>(*g<sub>2</sub>*)⟩ = in<sub><</sub>(*I*).

Now we prove *I* = ⟨*g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, ..., g<sub>s</sub>*⟩.
In general, ⟨*g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, ..., g<sub>s</sub>*⟩ ⊂ *I* holds since *g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, ..., g<sub>s</sub>* ∈ *I*. Hence it is enough to show that *I* ⊂ ⟨*g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, ..., g<sub>s</sub>*⟩.

Let 0 ≠ *f* ∈ *I* be a polynomial.
Then in<sub><</sub>(*f*) ∈ in<sub><</sub>(*I*).
Hence there exists an integer 1 ≦ *i* ≦ *s* and a monomial *w* such that in<sub><</sub>(*f*) = *w*・in<sub><</sub>(*g<sub>i</sub>*).
Then in<sub><</sub>(*f*) = in<sub><</sub>(*wg<sub>i</sub>*) by virtue of [lemma discussed earlier in the study material].
The initial term of *f* is of the form *c*・in<sub><</sub> and the initial term of *wg<sub>i</sub>* is of the form *c<sub>i</sub>*・in<sub><</sub>(*wg<sub>i</sub>*), where 0 ≠ *c*, *c<sub>i</sub>* ∈ *K*.

Now we let

> f<sup>(1)</sup> := *c<sub>i</sub>・f - c・wg<sub>i</sub>*.

Then one has f<sup>(1)</sup> ∈ *I* since *I* is an ideal and *f*, *g<sub>i</sub> ⊂ ⟨g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, ..., g<sub>s</sub>⟩* ∈ *I*.
Moreover, if f<sup>(1)</sup> = 0, then f = (*c/c<sub>i</sub>wg<sub>i</sub>* ∈ ⟨*g<sub>i</sub>*⟩ ⊂ ⟨*g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, ..., g<sub>s</sub>*⟩ and *I* ⊂ ⟨*g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, ..., g<sub>s</sub>*⟩.

#### My first problem

I can't quite follow the last step. How does proving that one element *f* of *I* is also an element of the ideal ⟨*g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, ..., g<sub>s</sub>*⟩ prove that all elements of the *I* are contained in ⟨*g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, ..., g<sub>s</sub>*⟩?

#### Back to the proof

Assume that *f<sup>(1)</sup>* ≠ 0.
Then one has in<sub><</sub>(*f<sup>(1)</sup>*) < in<sub><</sub>(*f*) and we can take a polynomial *f<sup>(2)</sup>* ∈ *I*  by using the same technique as we used for making *f<sup>(1)</sup>*.
If *f<sup>(2)</sup>* = 0, then *f<sup>(1)</sup>* ∈ ⟨*g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, ..., g<sub>s</sub>*⟩ and *f* ∈ ⟨*g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, ..., g<sub>s</sub>*⟩.

Assume that *f<sup>(2)</sup>* ≠ 0.
Then one has in<sub><</sub>(*f<sup>(2)</sup>*) < in<sub><</sub>(*f<sup>(1)</sup>*).
In general, in the case that *f<sup>(k-1)</sup>* ≠ 0, then we can take a polynomial *f<sup>(k)</sup>* ∈ *I* by using the same technique as we used for making *f<sup>(k-1)</sup>*.
If *f<sup>(k)</sup>* = 0, then *f<sup>(1)</sup>*, *f<sup>(2)</sup>*, ..., *f<sup>(k)</sup>* ∈ ⟨*g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, ..., g<sub>s</sub>*⟩.

Hence one has *f* ∈ ⟨*g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, ..., g<sub>s</sub>*⟩.
Thus it is enough to show that there exists an integer k ≧ 1 such that *f<sup>(k)</sup>* = 0.

Suppose that *f<sup>(k)</sup>* ≠ 0 for all *k* ≧ 1.
Then the infinite sequence of monomials

> in<sub><</sub>(*f*) > in<sub><</sub>(*f<sup>(1)</sup>*) > ... > in<sub><</sub>(*f<sup>(k)</sup>*) > ...

arises. However, this contradicts the statement of [another lemma discussed outside of this text].
Therefore it follows that there exists an integer *k* ≧ 1 such that _f<sup>(k)</sup> = 0.

#### My second problem

How exactly are *f<sup>(2)</sup>* onwards defined? Is it like *f<sup>(2)</sup>* := *c<sub>i</sub>・f<sup>(1)</sup> - c・wg<sub>i</sub>*, in which the parameters *c*, *i*, and *w* are all the same as for *f<sup>(1)</sup>*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Note that $f$ was taken to be an *arbitrary* (nonzero) element of $I$ (= *every* element of $I$ can be taken). Proving set inclusion $A \subset B$ [amounts to](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236037/question-about-proving-subset-inclusion) showing that every element of $A$ also lies in $B$. Zero is in $I$ by definition.
2. One takes the initial term $T_1$ of $f^{(1)}$ and finds an element $g_i$ of the Groebner basis with an initial term $T_1'$ that divides $T_1$. Then one multiplies $g_i$ by a certain monomial $m_i$ and a coefficient $\alpha_i$ so the result's initial term is exactly equal to $T_1$. Then $f^{(2)} = f^{(1)} - \alpha_i m_i g_i$ only contains terms that are *strictly* smaller than $T_1$.

Comment: Thanks!

My difficulty with point 1 was that even though it was an arbitrary function, the conclusion was made before even addressing the possibility that f^(1) ≠ 0, which could be true for some functions and false for others in the set.

But if I just move that conclusion to the end, I think I can follow it.